# Cannot Delete an Empty Folder in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, cmd.exe

I've used [this question's](https://superuser.com/questions/390735/cannot-delete-a-folder-in-windows-7) answer by user "Moab" to give myself permission to delete an *empty* folder, so that I no longer get "accessed denied".  However, now when I try removing this folder, I get a message that says "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."  This is merely my "eclipse" (IDE) folder that I totally emptied out and am trying to delete, but for some reason cannot.  I've tried quite a few things:

- Via Windows Explorer:

  - Right Click -> Delete

    ---
- Via Command Prompt

  - RD /S /Q eclipse
  - del /F eclipse
  - rmdir /S eclipse

I'm out of ideas, and I'd really like to delete this folder without having to install any software.  I've done a bit of research and this is all I found that I could try.  Does anyone have any other ideas?

Comment: Is Eclipse running?

Comment: No, it was not.

Comment: Do you have hidden files shown?  

Folder Options > View > Show Hidden Files, Folders, and Drives

Comment: I do have hidden files shown.  The problem is resolves now though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it appears I've already solved my problem... well, perhaps this answer will help anyone else who views this question with a similar problem!

How could one forget about Safe Mode?  I restarted my computer, held down F8 until I could choose to run the computer in Safe Mode with Command Prompt, and deleted the folder simply with `rmdir /S eclipse`, and finally issued a `shutdown -s`.  Now I'm back and the darn folder is actually gone!  It appears Safe Mode disallowed whatever "process" was "using" that eclipse folder from preventing me from deleting it.

Comment: Why on earth does Windows require a reboot to delete an empty folder? Further evidence that this OS is a joke, and we all have been punk'd... *sigh*

Answer (score 0):

1. at first, log off your machine and then remove this folder;
2. download "Unlocker" this software,install unlocker, right click this folder -->select unlocker --> select delete --> start